# Interrupted installation of InstallShield Wizard prevents re-installation

Tags: windows-10, installshield

InstallShield Wizard stopped at ~40% so I closed it with Task Manager and tried again. I get this error message:

[image]

I deleted `STUDIA` directory but error still shows up. I used CCleaner to clean the registry but it didn't help.

What I understand happened is that interrupted installation left some information (logs) and didn't delete them when I killed it and now this information doesn't allow me to install program again.

Where those logs are stored? Will I have to enter registry and delete something there?

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully managed to solve that problem, thanks to Robert (from the comment) for advising me to use Process Monitor.

Using Process Monitor I found that all those registry entries were located in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432NODE`, having gotten there I just deleted MITSUBISHI entry (a company which created a program I wanted to install). Everything works just fine now.